# Debian Автоматическая установка через preseed.cfg

Tags: debian

Установка проходит успешно, всё ок кроме того что не работает последняя строка в файле preseed.cfg
Она должна скачивать скрипт и копировать его в папку автозагрузки и он должен выполнится после загрузки ос. Но когда я её загружаю ничего не происходит, в этом каталоге нет этого файла....

```
d-i preseed/late_command string wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/..../script_debian_install.sh; chmod +x script_debian_install.sh; cp -R script_debian_install.sh /etc/init.d/; in-target /bin/bash /bin/neofetch;
```

Answer (score 1):

В установщике просто нет `wget` как такового. В минимальной установке, на сколько помню, и в самой системе wget не ставится если его какие зависимости из прочих tasksel не притянут.

Можно попросить поставить wget в устанавливаемую систему:

```
d-i pkgsel/include string wget
```

Затем через вспомогательную команду `in-target` запустить нужные команды будучи в chroot устанавливаемой системы:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target wget -O /tmp/post-install.sh "https://..." ; \
    chmod +x /target/tmp/post-install.sh; \
    in-target /tmp/post-install.sh;
```

Comment: А через curl это сделать можно?

Comment: если он есть, опять же. Я не помню и проверить не с руки. При запущенном установщике переключитесь на вторую или третью консоль, посмотрите какие команды в системе установщика есть